# MediaTomb fast image resize

Tags: linux, command-line, multimedia

The goal is to setup MediaTomb to (almost) instantaneously resize a 4-7MB jpeg from its original 8 or 12MP resolution down to somewhere about 1280x* so that it can be viewed on a mobile device.

Information on my setup: VM running arch with MediaTomb and another VM running arch and BubbleUPnP server to allow me to connect to all of my UPnP servers at home wherever I am. The problem is that I don't want to convert all of the pictures I take on trips. I simply want to browse them remotely and have the images resized quickly enough that I don't notice a lag when displaying/viewing pictures. Obviously the resizing is also to decrease the time it takes to display them.

I've tried using Imagemagick and it is very slow (5-10 seconds per picture) and `ffmpeg` is unsuitable for images over 5,000px. What are my options here?

VM 1: 2x3.00Ghz, 768mb ram (MediaTomb)
VM 2: 2x3.00Ghz, 512mb ram (XBMC, BubbleUPnP)

Original image resize script contained:

```
convert "$1" -filter lanczos -resize 1280x* "$2"
```

In the mediatomb config.xml I have added the following to their appropriate sections:

Under mimetype-profile-mappings:

```
<transcode mimetype="image/jpeg" using="jpeg-small"/>
```

And under profiles:

```
<profile name="jpeg-small" enabled="yes" type="external">
  <mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
  <agent command="convert" arguments="%in -resize 1280x1280 %out"/>
  <hide-original-resource>yes</hide-original-resource>
  <buffer size="10485760" chunk-size="131072" fill-size="2621440"/>
  <accept-url>no</accept-url>
  <first-resource>yes</first-resource>
</profile>
```

UPDATE: Now it "works", but I can only find sub-200x200 pictures when I browse MediaTomb share from a UPnP client. Not sure why as I'm telling it to make 1280 the maximum length of a side.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `mediatomb` has its own method for doing this internally. Perhaps this would do what you want.

`/etc/mediatomb/config.xml`:

```
  <transcoding enabled="yes">
    <mimetype-profile-mappings>
      <transcode mimetype="image/jpeg" using="jpeg-small"/>
    </mimetype-profile-mappings>
    <profiles>
      <profile name="jpeg-small" enabled="yes" type="external">
        <mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
        <agent command="/opt/jpeg-resize.sh" arguments="%in %out"/>
        <accept-url>no</accept-url>
        <first-resource>yes</first-resource>
        <hide-original-resource>no</hide-original-resource>
        <buffer size="4000000" chunk-size="20000" fill-size="20000"/>
        <resolution>1920x1080</resolution>
      </profile>
    </profiles>
  </transcoding>
```

You can then resize using this script, `/opt/jpeg-resize.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "---------" >> /opt/jpeg-resize.log
echo "Input  "$1 >> /opt/jpeg-resize.log
echo "Output "$2 >> /opt/jpeg-resize.log
cat "$1" | convert - -quality "75" -resize "1920x1080" fd:1 > "$2"
```

***Source:** [Transcode JPG to lower resolution](http://sourceforge.net/p/mediatomb/discussion/440751/thread/ef61c626)*.

#### Debugging mediatomb

If you're having problems determining what `mediatomb` is doing you can launch it in debug mode so that you get more verbose output.

```
$ mediatomb -D
```

Comment: Already doing approximately that. Convert just takes forever (I have timed it)

Comment: Got it working. I had to remove the -filter argument specifying which resize method to use. The problem  now is that all the pictures are now resized to under 200x200. My command-line is: convert "$1" -resize "1280x*" "$2"

What's going wrong?

Comment: @KG6ZVP - can you add more details? I can't help you more without additional info. For example what `-filter` argument are you referring to? Also can you show us exactly what you're doing? I use mediatomb as well and the above appears to be working fine for me.

Comment: Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @KG6ZVP - try running `mediatomb -D` in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified how you're using Imagemagick but there is no reason why it should be so slow. I just tested this on my laptop (i7, 2.67 GHz) and converted a 6.1MB .jpg to a 238K one in less than a second:

```
$ time convert -resize 577x577 foo.jpg bar.jpg 

real    0m0.883s
user    0m1.712s
sys     0m0.060s
$ ls -lh
total 6420
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon  238K Mar 19 03:24 bar.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon  6.1M Mar 19 03:17 foo.jpg
```

Just play around with the various options to get one that suits your needs.

Comment: Identical options on the command-line. However, the VM being used can't/won't have as much CPU power dedicated to it as your machine. It is running two cores at ~3.00Ghz each.

Comment: @KG6ZVP that's odd. As far as I know, `convert` does not multithread so it ran on a single, albeit i7, 2.67 core. I find it hard to believe that there can be _so_ much difference. In any case, I don't think you can do better than the IMageMagick tools though you might be able to optimize the options more.

Comment: I'll try updating the software again.

Comment: @KG6ZVP also, please [edit] your question and include both your VM's specs and the _exact_ command you are running.

Comment: Check the question again. I have added all other information